# Perl Less Than '<' Operator question

Tags: perl, operators

I am using a windows box with the latest version of ActivePerl installed from the following website [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl) and I am having an issue with a really simple concept of Less Than '<'.

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $a = 1;

if(1 < $a)
{
    print "true";
}
```

When I execute the script in a command prompt, "true" never prints out.  What simple logic am I missing here?  I have used this expression plenty of times in C++, C# and java but for some reason it is not working here.

If I missed something simple, please be nice. I have spent quite a bit of time wondering whats going on.

Thank you,

Wesley

Comment: One is not less than one.

Comment: I was looking for the statement `if(!(1 < $a))` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um... if $a is 1, the condition is false, and "true" will not print.  Did *I* miss something?

Comment: yep, you're right.  Sorry about that, I guess my brain just shut down